# Setting data to DataGridView in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a DataGridView on windows Form, just draged and droped from tools.
Now I want to set data to this gridview using DataSet or DataTable. How can set it by coding.
I am using SQL Server 2008 and VS 2010

Please Help me....

Comment: chech this example http://vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataGridSamp04232005050133AM/DataGridSamp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick example:

> Dim DS As New DataSet()
>   Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter()
>   Dim SelectQ as String = Query
>   Dim CN As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
>   DA.SelectCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SelectQ)
>   DACustomers.SelectCommand.Connection = CN
>   CN.Open
>   DA.fill(DS, "diseredTable")
>   CN.Close
>   Dim BS As New BindingSource
>   BS.DataSource = DS
>   BS.DataMember = ”desiredTable”
>   DataGridView1.DataSource = BS